# making Eclipse work in Fedora

Tags: eclipse, fedora

i would like to use Eclipse on Fedora. When i run a simple program i get "permission denied"

Any hints, links to tutorials to setup/configure Eclipse on Fedora 14 would be appreciated. No luck with Google "configure eclipse fedora".

I am fairly new to Fedora/Linux.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need permissions on the eclipse directory as well as on the workspace directory.

Comment: Hi Bozho, could you send me instructions?

Comment: @Baba `chmod 777 directory` :)

Comment: @Baba - create a blank workspace and try again. IT seems that the project file of some project is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search lead me to here :

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: yep saw that one too but not helping my particular case. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing permissions of the directory using

```
#chmod 777 directorylocation
```

Or

```
#chown user directorylocation
#chmod 755 directorylocation
```

For only user specific use